# Push Upgrade throws error 'No Access Exception'

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade

I am trying to push out an upgrade to one VF page (just including a forgotten JS library)

Most of the orgs that have the version of the App I'm trying to patch don't have any issues, but 2 / 50 or so throw the following exception:

```
You do not have sufficient privileges to access the controller: ..Controller of the page I updated...
```

I didn't change anything in the controller, but did add the JS library to the VF page.

Is this an administrator configuration issue I'm running into?

Comment: This has been confirmed as a "known issue" with professional edition orgs in SFDC

Answer (score 3):

According to [Push Upgrade of VF Page to PE Orgs fail with "You do not have sufficient privileges to access the controller: ControllerName"](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Re2XAAS) this issue is now fixed (assuming W-1238842 is the same known issue).